# Fiscal position implementation in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-accounting

I have seen one option in odoo accounting **"Fiscal Position"** under

> **Accounting => Configuration => Accounting => Fiscal Position**

I have checked it's features but I am not really getting at which point of time it's really useful or we can implement it where.

Features are very useful that all about tax and account mapping.

I would like to know it's importance, because I think so it's useful feature in odoo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Germany it's a really important feature. For example if you're a german company and sell goods mostly nationallly but sometimes internationally you don't have to take VAT from the customer (internationally), because Germany has double tax agreements with other countries.

But you will configure your Odoo products for the most used case -> national selling. Odoo gets lots of configured data like default tax and default accounts from the chosen product. But selling a product internationally means you have to take other taxes and accounts (in Germany for example!).

You could either handle that manually by changing taxes and accounts in invoices or you can use fiscal positions! Letter one will handle it on a much faster way.

---

Here a german example:

*Product "Software Odoo":* default tax 19% VAT, default Account 8400 (german SKR03, don't ask ;-))

*Fiscal Position "Not EU":*

tax mapping: 19% VAT -> no tax

account mapping: 8400 -> 8120

Creating an invoice for a non EU partner and this fiscal position, will set/map the taxes and accounts on every new invoice line automatically.

---

Actually that's no programming question and answer, but i've taken too much effort to write this, so i hope it will help you a bit ;-)

Comment: Awesome, really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Like @CZoellner said.

it's a way to configure odoo to change the taxs automaticly for a partner.

for example by default our taxes 19% but when we deal with import && export partner the taxes are not applicable so instead of removing this taxes manually because as you know when you select a product the taxes are loaded,

by defining the Fiscal position of partner this is don automaticly by odoo (19% tax --> 0% tax).